# USB wifi driver not loading until after graphical interface, and login is complete. How can I speed this up?

Tags: linux, debian, startup

I would like to move the launch level of usb wifi dongle. How would I go about doing that in linux? I looked in `/etc/init.d/` but I don't see my wifi dongle. I'm using these drivers https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux

Comment: Is the problem really that the driver isn't loaded before you log in? Or is the problem that the **network connection** doesn't start before you log in? How did you configure the network connection?

Answer (score 0):

Drivers are compiled into a kernel module to add access support in user-level for a certain device...nothing to do with starting processes. The important thing here is what is the daemon's name, to start with, since it is that daemon who is speaking with your WIFI through the device presented by the Kernel in user-space.

Starting order is, [as I pointed out in my answer to your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233964/121638), defined by the `??` in the link's name `S??<script-name>` in the `/etc/rc?.d` directory.
Alter the `??` of a specific script to alter its execution order.

Comment: I can't find the file for wifi in any of the /etc/rc{0..6}.d files though.